# How can you place a string into your query without using any quotation marks?

Tags: sql, code-injection

You have found a SQL injection vulnerability in a numeric field, but you need to use a string value in one of your attack payloads.How can you place a string into your query without using any quotation marks?

Comment: What is it that you have problems with? Is it that you don't understand the question that you have quoted?

Comment: Ther language used suggests it was formed by someone who knows the answer.  Definitely Homework.

Answer (score 2):

Use a parametrized query instead of concatenation strings. [Guide to SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 0):

Escape ' with ''

INSERT INTO Foo(A)VALUES('GEORGE''S CAT')